# I can install new Wordpress plugins, but I can't update existing ones

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I recently migrated my Wordpress site to another server. Everything is working properly now, except I am unable to update Wordpress plugins that were installed before the migration. I *am able to install new ones*, which confuses me.

Steps I've taken so far:

- Set permissions of wp-content and sub-directories to 755
- Set permissions of files within wp-content and sub-directories to 644

I am not prompted for FTP information when installing new plugins.

Comment: "_I am unable to update Wordpress plugins that were installed before the migration_". What exactly happens when you try to update an existing plugin?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to include the error. It says this: "Update Failed: The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions."

Answer (score 0):

Can you attempt to delete the "/wp-content/upgrade" directory and just create it as an empty folder?

Wordpress can be a bit tough when it comes to migration, and based on experience this has been the cause of the issue at times.

Comment: I tried this, now I'm receiving a different error: "Update Failed: Could not create directory."